# Modify multiple lines of an XML file using command line

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, xml

Looking at text below, how do I go about replacing multiple lines of text?

```
<Model500>
ABC
BCD 
CDE
</Model500>
<Model500>
123
234
345
</Model500>
```

The output could be like below

```
<Model500>
AAA
BBB 
CCC
</Model500>
<Model500>
111
333
555
</Model500>
```

I would like to accomplish this with `sed` but any command line utility that works with Bash will work. Should I be using a loop to accomplish this?

Comment: bash has a lot of features, but it's not a text editor

Comment: what's the rule?

Comment: Well I do understand that the bash is not supposed to be used for extensive text editing, but I thought one can use 'sed' for that purpose?

Comment: I got confused when you said "any bash method" -- bash != sed

Comment: Are the replacements based on rules, or is the end result not related to the initial values?

Comment: The end results are not related to the initial values. This code is just a snippet that I intend to integrate into a bigger set. For this instance, I would replace the ABC, BCD, etc with the user input. I am just looking for ways to easily modify the XML file where a certain variable repeats. It turns out 'sed' isn't the best way to modify XML files.

Comment: Use any text editor in bash.(vi, vim, nano)

Answer (score 10):

Use a proper [xml](/questions/tagged/xml)tool, in shell, [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) is a good one :

```
xmlstarlet edit -L -u "//Model500[1]"  -v "AAA                                                                
BBB
CCC" file.xml

xmlstarlet edit -L -u "//Model500[2]" -v "111                                                               
333
555" file.xml


cat file.xml
```

The expression `//Model500[2]` is a [Xpath expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

#### NOTE ¹

you need to enclose your xml with a tag like :

```
<root>
...
</root>
```

to be XML valid. I hope you cutted the XML file for the purpose of your question.

#### NOTE ²

You can also use [python](/questions/tagged/python), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) etc... and a proper xml lib.

In [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Simple;

my $xml_file = 'file.xml';

my $xml = XMLin(
    $xml_file,
    KeepRoot => 1,
    ForceArray => 1,
);

$xml->{root}->[0]->{Model500}->[0] = "AAA\nBBB\nCCC\n";
$xml->{root}->[0]->{Model500}->[1] = "111\n222\n333\n";

XMLout(
    $xml,
    KeepRoot => 1,
    NoAttr => 1,
    OutputFile => $xml_file,
);
```

Comment: Woah I have not heard of this tool but the format on this seems much more intuitive. Thanks. I will give this one a try.